# How can I print values from a text file in the console?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to read some values from a `Values.txt` file and then print them in the console using C#. Everything appears to work. I've debugged the code and found nothing wrong and the program is compiling. The problem is that the values wont appear on the console. It just prints empty lines.

Here's my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestFileReadTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("Values.txt");
            string line = "";

            while (line != null)
            {
                line = myReader.ReadLine();
                if (line!= null)
                    Console.WriteLine();
            }
            myReader.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Allo");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(line)`

Comment: Are you trying to read one line or the entire file? This looks like it'll only read the first line. Also, as @JasonP commented: `Console.WriteLine(line);` should fix it.

Comment: @Brandon - `while (line != null)` - this will read more than one line, unless there's only one line in the file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere do you actually print the values to the console.

You print an empty line here:

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

You probably meant to print the `line` variable:

```
Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: Oh my god... "facepalm". Thank you, I feel stupid now! :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add variable `line`to `Console.WriteLine()`:

```
while (line != null)
{
    line = myReader.ReadLine();
    if (line!= null)
        Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```